# How do I make Yocto include the `iiod` package?

Tags: cmake, package, yocto, bitbake, iio

I have added the [libiio](https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/libiio) library to my Yocto image with the [libiio recipe](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/57509/) from `meta-oe`, and while the library files are added to the image, `iiod` is not.

This part of the recipe says there should be a file added to `sbin`, and there is not.

```
FILES:${PN}-iiod = " \
    ${sbindir}/iiod \
    ${systemd_system_unitdir}/iiod.service \
"
```

Checking this [Cmake file](https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/libiio/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) of the library, I tried adding `EXTRA_OECMAKE += "-DWITH_SYSVINIT"` to a `.bbappend` file, however that didn't seem to do anything.

Then seeing that the recipe inherits `systemd` I added `DISTRO_FEATURES:append = " systemd"` to my `conf/local.conf`, and still no effect.

In the `log.do_install` file, there are these lines:

```
-- Installing: /home/<name/yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/cortexa9t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/libiio/0.23-r0/image/usr/sbin/iiod
-- Set runtime path of "/home/<name>/yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/cortexa9t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/libiio/0.23-r0/image/usr/sbin/iiod" to ""
-- Installing: /home/<name>/yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/cortexa9t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/libiio/0.23-r0/image/lib/systemd/system/iiod.service
```

And the `log.do_oackage` has this line:

```
DEBUG: runstrip: ['arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-strip', '--remove-section=.comment', '--remove-section=.note', '/home/<name>/yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/cortexa9t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/libiio/0.23-r0/package/usr/sbin/iiod']
```

How do I make Yocto include the `iiod` package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " libiio-iiod"
```